# What's my tax status?

Tags: taxes, uk-citizens

I am retired, and been living outside of the UK for over 10 years. I spend most of my time in Greece (but under the 183 days tax requirement).

The rest of the time, I spend in Asia and the UK, all under the tax requirement days.

Now my bank is asking for the new CRS forms to be filled in with a tax number, or to give an explanation of why I don't have one.

What the correct response to these questions?

Comment: I suppose the correct answer depends on whether you have a tax number and, if not, why.

Comment: I am not resident anywhere for longer than the time requirement for tax so therefor do not have a tax number, ,must be many other people in a similar position as this as I have met several over the years when traveling,

Comment: I am British expat , left the UK in 2006 , after being self employed for 30 years Plus.
I spend 5 Months a year in Greece , 5 Months in Asia , and the remainder traveling in Europe.
I am now being asked for a TIN number , but as I am not in any one country I cannot provide this.
I  have no income other than savings and a few dividends.
Any advice on my tax position

Comment: You might consider asking this at [money.SE].  Some countries allow you to apply for a tax number even if you don't pay tax.  If that's not possible then it seems like you ought to comply with the requirement through the second option: explain why you don't have the number.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty new requirement. The EU only adopted this January 1, 2016. A reasonable answer would be that you hadn't heard of the requirement until now, which is probably the case for 99% percent of bank account holders in the relevant jurisdictions. There is also the point that you are apparently not actually resident, for tax purposes, in any country under the CRS. As long as you can demonstrate this clearly, that should suffice.